# Probleme to link my stub with newlib with arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm, bare-metal

I'm trying to compile a small proof of work tath run lua code on the rasperry pi zero bare-metal.

All my object file and lua's have been compiled with similar options. I tried with and without the `-nostdlib` and `-lc -lgcc` but the output is the same.

Commande:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc \
    -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv6zk -mtune=arm1176jzf-s \
    -g -O0 \
    -Wl,-z,max-page-size=0x04,-T,linker.ld \
    -nostdlib \
    ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lapi.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lauxlib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lbaselib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lcode.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lcorolib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lctype.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/ldblib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/ldebug.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/ldo.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/ldump.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lfunc.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lgc.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/linit.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/liolib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/llex.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lmathlib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lmem.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/loadlib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lobject.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lopcodes.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/loslib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lparser.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lstate.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lstring.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lstrlib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/ltable.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/ltablib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/ltm.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lundump.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lutf8lib.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lvm.o ./lua/lua-5.4.4/src/lzio.o \
    ./.build/startup.o ./.build/start.o ./.build/main.o ./.build/bootstrap.lua.o ./.build/0stubs.o \
    -lc \
    -lgcc \
    -lm
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): in function `_fstat_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/fstatr.c:55: undefined reference to `_fstat'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-openr.o): in function `_open_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/openr.c:50: undefined reference to `_open'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-timesr.o): in function `_times_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/timesr.c:52: undefined reference to `_times'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-unlinkr.o): in function `_unlink_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/unlinkr.c:47: undefined reference to `_unlink'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/writer.c:49: undefined reference to `_write'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): in function `_close_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/closer.c:47: undefined reference to `_close'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-gettimeofdayr.o): in function `_gettimeofday_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/gettimeofdayr.c:62: undefined reference to `_gettimeofday'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): in function `_isatty_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/isattyr.c:52: undefined reference to `_isatty'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-linkr.o): in function `_link_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/linkr.c:53: undefined reference to `_link'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): in function `_lseek_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/lseekr.c:49: undefined reference to `_lseek'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): in function `_read_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/readr.c:49: undefined reference to `_read'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): in function `_kill_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:53: undefined reference to `_kill'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/arm/v5te/hard/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): in function `_getpid_r':
/build/newlib-wFsRXh/newlib-3.3.0/build/arm-none-eabi/arm/v5te/hard/newlib/libc/reent/../../../../../../../../newlib/libc/reent/signalr.c:83: undefined reference to `_getpid'
```

My 0stubs.c file:

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>

/* A helper function written in assembler to aid us in allocating memory */
extern caddr_t _get_stack_pointer(void);


/* Increase program data space. As malloc and related functions depend on this,
   it is useful to have a working implementation. The following suffices for a
   standalone system; it exploits the symbol _end automatically defined by the
   GNU linker. */
caddr_t _sbrk( int incr )
{
    extern char _end;
    static char* heap_end = 0;
    char* prev_heap_end;

    if( heap_end == 0 )
        heap_end = &_end;

     prev_heap_end = heap_end;

     heap_end += incr;
     return (caddr_t)prev_heap_end;
}

int close(int file) {
  return -1;
}

char *__env[1] = { 0 };
char **environ = __env;

#include <errno.h>
#undef errno
extern int errno;
int execve(char *name, char **argv, char **env) {
  errno = ENOMEM;
  return -1;
}

int fork(void) {
  errno = EAGAIN;
  return -1;
}

int kill(int pid, int sig) {
  errno = EINVAL;
  return -1;
}

int link(char *old, char *new) {
  errno = EMLINK;
  return -1;
}

int fstat(int file, struct stat *st) {
  st->st_mode = S_IFCHR;
  return 0;
}

int getpid(void) {
  return 1;
}

int isatty(int file) {
  return 1;
}

int lseek(int file, int ptr, int dir) {
  return 0;
}

int open(const char *name, int flags, int mode) {
  return -1;
}

int read(int file, char *ptr, int len) {
  return 0;
}

int times(struct tms *buf) {
  return -1;
}

int unlink(char *name) {
  errno = ENOENT;
  return -1; 
}

int wait(int *status) {
  errno = ECHILD;
  return -1;
}

int write(int file, char *ptr, int len) {
  int todo;

  for (todo = 0; todo < len; todo++) {
    //outbyte (*ptr++);
  }
  return len;
}

void abort(void){
    while(1){}
}

void exit(int status){
    while(1){}
}
```